# Using DLookup to populate a text box after a combo box is updated

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to populate a text box by looking up a value after a combo box is updated. Right now in the combo box "after update" event I have:

Me.Text42 = DLookUp("field","query","Baseline=" & [Combo26])

But that is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the `Baseline` column in `query` is defined as text data rather than numeric, then you need

```
Me.Text42 = DLookUp("field","query","Baseline='" & [Combo26] & "'")
```

If this is not the problem, can you post more details. What appears in Text42? Nothing or `#Error`? Have you tried putting a break point in the code and testing the value of your `DLookup` function in the immediate pane?